# Outlook 2007 w/ Exchange Slow to Open Messages with Return Receipts?

Tags: performance, microsoft-outlook-2007

I've got a user on Outlook 2007 connecting to Exchange 2003.  When she opens an email with a return receipt, it takes about 30-60 seconds.  I've found one reference to this problem via search, but no solutions.

The machine is a 2.6Ghz P4 w/ 512MB DDR266.  One thing of note is that the user's mailbox size is very large (>3GB).  Regular messages open fine.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to delete and recreate the user's Outlook profile.  Everything's snappy now.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem before, and im not sure you'll like the answer

I uninstalled office2k7, installed office2k3, connected (took 1/2 second), let the folders sync, upgraded to office 2k7 and finally had success.

Hope this saves others from similar frustration and wasted time.

Comment: This machine was just upgraded from Office 2003...